# Aurelia: Wizardry With Binding Behaviors with value converter?

Tags: binding, aurelia, behavior

I've been experimenting with Ashley Grant's post: https://bl.ocks.org/AshleyGrant/07e645e46f7cc945b4e43c4ec80c6424

and was wondering if anyone knows how to go one step further and apply a value converter after using the 'dynamicExpression' Binding Behavior.  Something like this:
`<input type="text" value.bind="model & dynamicExpression:field.expression | formatNumber:'$###,###.00'" />`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/binding-behaviors#introduction states that value converters only observe the values passing by, but behaviors have full access to binding context.

I guess if you rewrite your formatNumber as a behavior - you can chain them.